# Lua Script Output separate extra lines

Tags: pdftex, lua

My Input Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\maketitle

In this article we denote 
\begin{equation}
\nu:=\frac{1}{\gamma-1}. \label{Nu}
\end{equation}

Let us fix a Let us fix $H^{\mathrm{op}}$ as it.

\begin{align}
v'^2_{i}&=abc
\end{align}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One should not attempt to prove statements so obvious that nothing more obvious exists with which to prove them.
\item One should prove all theorems which are not quite clear and in the proofs one should use only very obvious axioms or theorems which are accepted or proved.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**texlua filter.lua < filename.tex > output.tex**

Output.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amscd}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{author}

\maketitle


In this article we denote 

\begin{equation}

\nu:=\frac{1}{\gamma-1}. \label{Nu}

\end{equation}



Let us fix a Let us fix $H^{\mathrm{op}}$ as it.



\begin{align}

v^{\prime 2}_{i}&=abc

\end{align}



\begin{enumerate}
\item One should not attempt to prove statements so obvious that nothing more obvious exists with which to prove them.

\item One should prove all theorems which are not quite clear and in the proofs one should use only very obvious axioms or theorems which are accepted or proved.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

My filter.lua:

```
for line in io.lines() do
  line = line:gsub([[%'%^(.-)%_]], [[^{\prime %1}_]])
  line = line:gsub([[\vspace{(.-)}\\]], [[\vspace{%1}]])
  line = line:gsub([[\end{equation}\\]], [[\end{equation}]])
  line = line:gsub([[%^\mathrm{(.-)}]], [[^{\mathrm %1}]])
  print(line)
end
```

When storing the **output.tex** extra line is present all the cases. See above. How to solve this problem?

I know **`texlua filter.lua < filename.tex | make4ht -j sample "mathml,mathjax"`**. But updations are not updated in the LaTeX file.

Comment: And your `filter.lua`?

Comment: The lua you posted does not add extra lines.

Comment: @David: You can see after `\begin{equation}` one enter mark found after running `texlua filter.lua < filename.tex > output.tex`. This is the problem for me. I have using LuaLaTeX version is `Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `print(line)` with `io.write(line)`. The latter isn't supposed to add newlines.